# Surrogate uteri (exaggerated brood parasitism) as an adaptation?

Tags: science-based, evolution, reproduction

Under what circumstances would a species develop an adaptation to employ surrogate wombs of their own species or others?

The species implants its zygotes/eggs in the uterus/brood pouch of a surrogate mother/father, of its own species or another, which gestates and births to the offspring.

This is not endoparasitism, parasitoids, or external egg laying. This is an exaggerated form of brood parasitism.

Comment: You mean a version of **parasites** or **symbiotes**. So the answer is: it has already happened.

Comment: I think the question is what environmental pressures would make a species become a parasite or symbiote. I have no idea... what made the first cuckoo lay its eggs in another bird's nest? What made the next generation keep it up?

Comment: @SRM - the brood parasitism of cuckoos, cowbirds etc probably evolved from the much more widespread phenomenon of 'egg dumping'. This is where a female lays some eggs in her own nest, but sneaks a few into her neighbours' nests too. She quite literally does not keep all her eggs in one basket!  Lots of species of duck do this. The cuckoo duck (yes that's a real bird) takes it a step further and lays all its eggs in a gull's nest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**If your babies are parasitic**. Plenty species of wasp inject their eggs into a living host - a caterpillar or spider. The eggs hatch inside and the larvae eat their way though the host. This does not end well for the caterpillars and spiders.

**If your babies come packaged in handy capsules**. If you lay eggs, you can hand your kids over to a nanny or nursemaid even before they are born, and not have to bother with any of that tedious incubation stuff. Humans have to give birth to the kid and only then pass it to a wet nurse. Birds, crocodiles and platypuses can start much earlier. However, if you come from a species where the baby instantly imprints on the adult it sees when it hatches, you'll have to remember to be present at the hatching or the kid will refuse to ever bond with you. If your baby is more like a human newborn, where mum and baby take a bit longer to fixate on each other and adopting older kids works just fine, then that's less vital. Nanny can do all the dull nappy changing stuff and you can swan about like the Lady of the Manor.

**If you are a marsupial.** Marsupials effectively have 2 wombs: an internal one and an external one - the pouch. Have another female on standby when you give birth and pop the baby in her pouch not yours. She'll probably have to take hormone tablets so that her pouch and teats are ready to accept a joey. Alternatively, if your marsupials had evolved into a eusocial species like the naked mole rat (where one queen gives birth to all the offspring), then the nearby females will have been primed by the queen's hormones to have their pouches in optimal condition for her babies. Naked mole rat queens could churn out offspring at an alarming rate if someone else was responsible for shoving milk into the babies as they go through the bulk of their development.

**If birth is more dangerous than a fetal transplant and/or you are a high status individual whose life must not be risked.** I believe that pedigree cattle are sometimes conceived by IVF and implanted into the womb of non-pedigree cows. Firstly this means that the farmer can produce dozens of pedigree calves a year instead of just the one which his prize cow could gestate naturally. Secondly there is no risk to the prize cow from birth complications. Perhaps billionaires or royalty employ surrogates of their own species to do this.

Answer (score 8):

When giving birth means death. Octopuses are *very* smart creatures - but they die after laying eggs, which results in the inability to transfer knowledge from one individual to its offspring. A similar species might get around this through *social* evolution - a few surrogates breed and die, while others bring up the young, remaining celebrate through this period, acting as parents/mentors. This would allow knowledge to be passed down.

At some point tho, this is *inefficient*, losing mature members of the community, and having the next generation brought up by others. Sidestepping biological reproduction through artifical wombs would allow new generations without losses due to mortality while giving birth or 
laying eggs.

Comment: Gave you a +1. The octopuses would have to do some genetic engineering or knowledge of biochemistry, since their whole metabolism switches over from growth of body to producing eggs/sperm. They even start to cannibalise their own tissue in some species. So those non-breeders would need a mechanism to stop sexual maturation occurring. Take a pill every day?

Comment: Or initially have younger pre breeding individuals take care of they young in a sort of creche system. While you lose the oldest, as they give birth, there's still a social structure. I suppose as time went on yeah, Birth control pills for non breeders and/or genetic or pharmaceutical changes would be plausible.